# Getting NullPointerException while parsing JSONArray

Tags: java, json, arrays

Working on JSON for the first time. The problem is -

I am getting null pointer exception even after handling the empty json array.
I have created a josn file file in which there is an empty array. my json file is like-

```
{
   "name" :"jsonObject",

   "myArray" : []
}
```

For parsing I am using json.simple-1.1.1.jar.
My java code is -

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject rootObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(filePath));           

        String str = (String) rootObj.get("name");

        JSONArray array = (JSONArray)rootObj.get("array");

        if(array.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("array is null");
```

In json file the array will be null sometimes and sometimes not. What is the proper way to handle it?

Comment: Maybe it's just a copy-paste typo, but shouldn't it be `rootObj.get("myArray")`?

Comment: so stupid of me!!....

Answer (score 2):

Your member's name is `myArray` not `array`. This works:

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) rootObj.get("myArray");
```

To check if the member is there use `has()`:

```
if(rootObj.has("myArray")) {
    JSONArray array = rootObj.getJSONArray("myArray"); // getJSONArray avoids cast :-)
    // ...
}
```

See:
http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29